# pymongo problem: TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, websocket, pymongo

I try to insert some users info into my database, so I create two scripts using python, the first one is the server, who still awake and listen to every new client who connect, and capable also to read the user data (Read data from the client app) and finally write the data inside a `file.txt` and the second script, capable to read the data which stored inside the `file.txt` and finally insert it in my Mongo database.

This is an example of the data that I want to insert:

```
 {"id":"12345", "user":"someone2021", "full name":"someone full name", "email":"someone@mail.com", "phone":"xxxxxxxx", "password":"*********"}
```

So in the server side, I create this script:

**Server.py**

```
import socket
port = 80
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

print("******************************")
print("server listening...")

while True:
    client, adr = s.accept()
    print(f"got connection from ",adr)
    data = client.recv(1024)

    if (data.decode("utf-8")!= None):
        with open('user.txt', 'w') as writer:
             writer.write(data.decode("utf-8"))
    client.close()
```

For the server script, I don't have any problem, everything work fine, and below the user.txt file result:

[image]

And finally the insert data to database script:

**InsertToMongoDB.py**:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = myclient["CompanyProject"]
mycol = mydb["Clients"]

str =""
with open('user.txt', 'r') as reader:
        for i in reader:
                str += i
info={ str }

x = mycol.insert_one(info)
f = open("id.txt","wb")
f.write("The object id: ",x.inserted_ids)
print(x.inserted_ids)
```

This script show me always an error, below the output error:

```
    x = mycol.insert_one(info)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 692, in insert_one
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 502, in validate_is_document_type
    raise TypeError("%s must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, "
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

I'm using in my work the Ubuntu 20 OS, and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the input type is a set and not a dict, which is not acceptable in Mongo.

So to solve this problem, you need to convert the string data to a dict, in python there is a function is name `eval()` can convert easily a string value to a dict, but is necessary to respect the form of the data that you want to convert, that's mean, you need to add the `{}` in the first and in the end of the string, otherwise, you will get an error.
So for the string data, you need to send to the server a string with this format:

```
{"id":"12345", "user":"someone2021", "full name":"someone full name", "email":"someone@mail.com", "phone":"xxxxxxxx", "password":"*********"}
```

And finally the `InsertToMongoDB.py` script should look like this one:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()
mydb = myclient["CompanyProject"]
mycol = mydb["Clients"]

strData = ''
with open('user.txt', 'r') as reader:
    for i in reader:
        strData += i
str_dict = eval(strData)
print(str_dict)
x = mycol.insert_one(data_dict).inserted_id
f = open("id.txt","wb")
f.write("The object id: ",x.inserted_ids)
print(x.inserted_ids)
```

Now if you want to read a special data, for example the user name, just write this code:

```
print(str_dict['user'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `info={ str }` does not create a `dict` but a `set` so that's why you get this error message. Also, when reading from file, you will always get strings. In addition, according to your screenshot, the string are not valid dict so you will need to parse them by hand.

You should work on your encoding and parsing function. Personally I would use `json` to dump and parse the data, but if you want to keep your code, you can try this in `InsertToMongoDB.py`:

```
# supposing you have multiple lines in user.txt file
data = []
with open('user.txt', 'r') as reader:
    for row in reader.readlines():
        data_dict = {}
        for key_val, in row.replace('"', "").split(','):
            for i in key_val.split(":"):
                key = i[0].strip() # remove trailing space
                val = i[1]
                data_dict[key] = val
        data.append(data_dict)

for i in data:
    x = mycol.insert_one(i)
```

Comment: You are right, the problem was because the type of data is not a dict, but the easy way is just to add the file inside data_dict directly. I add an answer, it's work for me and solve the problem, any way thanks you give me an idea to solve the problem.